# 'database is locked' in sqlite in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

Hello friends I have searched a lot about this error. I found some advice like you must use sqlite_finalize() statement and I use it. Have a look on my code.

> -(void) updatePostingsForLike:(NSString *)postingKey isLiked:(NSString *)isLiked{
>
> ```
>   [self initWithDB]; 
>   sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
>
>   if(sqlite3_open([[self dbPath] UTF8String],&(db)) == SQLITE_OK) {
>
>       NSString *str=[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"update posting set isLiked='%@' where postKey='%@'",isLiked,postingKey];
>       const char *sql=[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>       int status;
>       status= sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
>
>       if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(stmt))
>       {
>           NSLog(@"%s",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
>
>       }
>
>       sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
>
>       [self closeConnection];
>
>   }}
> ```

I followed all the rules. I can update my record only once. First time only. It throws error on second time. What should be the solution ? I stuck in such problem since last 2 days !

Comment: Where does it throw the error?  You should return the error structures from sqlite calls.  Those are the best indicators of what should be done.

Comment: @Downloadmore: Are you accessing this database from any other connection or using the same connection in any other thread? Remember that SQLite does a database level lock!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
-(void) updatePostingsForLike:(NSString *)postingKey isLiked:(NSString *)isLiked
{

   [self initWithDB]; 
   sqlite3_stmt *statement;

   if(sqlite3_open([[self dbPath] UTF8String],&db) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
      NSString* query=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"update posting set isLiked='%@' where   postKey='%@'",isLiked,postingKey];
      const char *query_stmt = [query UTF8String];

     if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
     {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        { 
            sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        } 
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
     }
    sqlite3_close(db);
  }
}
```